# Buscar substring exacto en una frase

Tags: python, algoritmos, nlp

primera vez que publico espero hacerlo bien, me propuse hacer el siguiente ejercicio que estaba propuesto para desarrollarse en java pero yo lo quiero hacer en python:

Un programa que permita ingresar una palabra (a buscar) y tantas frases como el usuario quiera (para terminar debe ingresar FIN). Osea, buscar un string exacto en cada frase y si la contiene debe ser impresa junto con las demás frases que contengan la palabra a buscar ej:

perro

El perro come su hueso.
Hoy hace mucho calor en la ciudad.
José y su perro caminan por la costanera.
Josefina tiene dos perros de peluche en su habitación.

El programa sólo debe imprimir en consola las oraciones "El perro come su hueso." y "José y su
perro caminan por la costanera."

[Este código contenía errores, mas abajo lo mejoré]

```
    palabra=input()
    bandera=0
    contadorDiferencias=0
    v=[] #vector para ir guardando las frases que cumplan la condicion
    while True:
        f=input()
        bandera=f.find(palabra)

        if f[len(f)-1]==palabra[len(palabra)-1]: #si está la palabra y la ultima letra de la frase es igual a la ultima de la palabra:
            for i in range(len(palabra)): #verificará si coincide palabra por palabra el string
                if palabra[i] == f[bandera]:                                        
                    bandera=bandera+1
                else:
                    contadorDiferencias=contadorDiferencias+1 #en caso de no haber coincidencia lo aumentamos
                    bandera=bandera+1

            if contadorDiferencias == 0:
                v.append(f)

        elif f[bandera+len(palabra)]== " " or f[bandera+len(palabra)]== "." or f[bandera+len(palabra)]==",":        #para casos en los que el usuario haya agregado algo más    

            for i in range(len(palabra)):
                if palabra[i] == f[bandera]:                                        
                    bandera=bandera+1
                else:
                    contadorDiferencias=contadorDiferencias+1
                    bandera=bandera+1

            if contadorDiferencias == 0: #si se encontró una diferencia agregarla al vector
                v.append(f)

        if f == "FIN":
            break

    for i in range(len(v)):
        print(v[i])
```

Al ejecutar el problema está aqui, me dice que está fuera de rango el index (IndexError: string index out of range):

```
elif f[bandera+len(palabra)]== " " or f[bandera+len(palabra)]== "." or f[bandera+len(palabra)]==",":
```

Esto es lo que no entiendo, si con el primer if tomo los casos en los que la ultima letra de la frase es la ultima letra de la palabra, en el elif solo entran los casos en los que hay "algo" despues de la palabra entonces por qué estaría fuera de rango el indice? La verdad estoy muy enredado.

Edit: Ya mejoré el codigo, quedó asi:

```
    palabra=input()
    bandera=0
    v=[]
    while True:
        f=input()
        bandera=f.find(palabra)
        if bandera != -1:   #pa descartar frases en las que no esté la palabra y q el for no de error buscandola

            if len(f) == len(palabra) or f[bandera+len(palabra)]== " " or f[bandera+len(palabra)]== "." or f[bandera+len(palabra)]=="," or f[bandera+len(palabra)]==";":
                 v.append(f)

        elif f == "FIN":
            break

    print("------Frases que contienen la palabra exacta------ ") #bueno, casi :(
    for i in range(len(v)):
        print(v[i])
```

Comment: Lo primero decirte que es posible hacer que este código sea más sencillo. Por ejemplo, el último elemento de una lista se puede obtener con `lista[-1]` en lugar de calcularlo con `lista[len(lista)-1]`. Por otro lado, el método `str.find` retorna `-1` cuando no encuentra nada, caso que no estás considerando. Si intentas buscar `perro` en `FIN` se sale del tamaño y de ahí el error.

Comment: Gracias por responder, no sabia eso del retorno -1, ya modifiqué el código y saque lo que sobraba, está casi perfecto, solo falla cuando se ingresa el substring no como palabra sino entremedio de otros caracteres esto antes de la palabra exacta, osea que sí está pero después del substring por lo que no considera que está ej: gato, "los gatos no es lo mismo que gato", en esa frase falla

Comment: Entiendo lo que dices. Si la primera palabra encontrada no coincide exactamente, tendrás que seguir buscando en el resto de la frase. Al método `str.find` se le puede decir a partir de qué posición buscar para que siga buscando. Pero se complica mucho, ya que también puede ocurrir al revés: por ejemplo, puede que sea `ágata` cuando buscas `gata`. Si buscas algo más robusto, te recomiendo que mires las *expresiones regulares*  (módulo [re](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html)). Puedes sacar fácilmente todas las palabras de una frase con `re.findall('\w+', frase)`.

Answer (score 1):

si puedes usar librerías externas prueba NLTK:

Para lo que comentas usaría lo siguiente:

```
import nltk
texto = "Perro gato loro"
texto = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(texto))
resultado = texto.concordance('Perro')


#También puedes hacerlo con una lista:

import nltk
texto = "Perro gato loro"
texto = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(texto))
palabras_a_buscar = ['Perro', 'loro']

for i in palabras_a_buscar:
resultado = texto.concordance(i)
```

Espero que te ayude! D

Answer (score 1):

Es fácil sacar todas las palabras de una frase usando [expresiones regulares](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html):

```
words = re.findall('\w+', frase)
```

Aplicándolo al problema:

```
import re

pat = re.compile('\w+')  # allwords extractor

palabra = input()

frases = []
while True:
    frase = input()
    if frase == "FIN":
        break
    elif palabra in pat.findall(frase):
        frases.append(frase)

print("------Frases que contienen la palabra exacta------ ")
for frase in frases:
    print(frase)
```

Answer (score 0):

Si no he entendido mal, el objetivo es obtener un algoritmo que dada una palabra y una frase te indique si la palabra está dentro de la frase o no. Una vez obtenido este algoritmo, este se ejecutaría para cada frase introducida por el usuario y guardaría las frases que contengan la palabra.

Si es así, creo que la solución es más sencilla de lo que planteas. Te pongo un posible código del algoritmo que detecta si una palabra está en una frase.

```
palabra = "que"
v=[]

f = "Hola que tal"
palabra = palabra.lower()
f = f.lower()
f = f.replace(".", " ")
f = f.replace(",", " ")

if(palabra in f.split()):
  v.append(f)
```

Como ves, he optado por realizar un tratamiento a la frase para asegurarnos de que encontramos la coincidencia.

- Convertimos a minúsculas la frase y la palabra
- Eliminamos los signos de puntuación que puedan delimitar la palabra
- Partimos la frase por cada espacio y comprobamos si la palabra está en la lista de palabras obtenidas.

Este último paso es necesario, puesto que si hacemos la instrucción "in" a toda la frase nos devolverá "True" a pesar de que la palabra no sea exactamente la misma. Para que nos entendamos, sin partir la frase en palabras, si buscamos la palabra "perro" y en la frase pone "perros", nos dirá que ha encontrado la palabra, cuando realmente no es así.

Espero haberte resultado de utilidad.

Answer (score 0):

La mayoria de lenguajes de programación tienen un metodo "contains" o similar para Strings, basicamente comprueba si una string contiene otra.

En el caso de Python dispone del operador `in`.

Por ejemplo

```
str = "Messi el mejor jugador de fútbol de la historia"
"fútbol" in str
>>>True
"soccer" in str
>>>False
```

Por desgracia desconozco Python y no puedo explicarte el resto mas que en pseudo código, cualquier duda pregunta. Básicamente necesarias:

1- Obtienes i guardas la palabra a buscar

2-Obtienes todas las frases, compruebas si es "FIN", si no lo es las guardas en una lista o array. Si es fin pasas al paso 3

3- con un for each te recorres el array con algo similar a:

```
for frase in array:
    if palabra in frase:
        print frase
```